# MIPS Double Recursion Problem " Can't expand stack segment by 16 bytes to 524288 bytes"

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I'm trying to implement a double recursion program using MIPS that follows this pseudocode:

```
procedure DRAGON(order, sign)
    if order = 0 then
        Move forward
    else
        DRAGON(order-1; 1)
        Turn 90sign
        DRAGON(order-1; -1)
```

This is what I have until now, but when I run it, I get this error:

```
Can't expand stack segment by 16 bytes to 524288 bytes.
Use -lstack # with # > 524288
```

I'm new to MIPS so it's really difficult for me to debug this. I suspect that it's probably because I'm making infinite recursive calls, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Could anyone be able to help point out what the problem is?

```
        .data
# SVG path segment commands
up:     .asciiz "v-5"
right:  .asciiz "h5"
down:   .asciiz "v5"
left:   .asciiz "h-5"

# Print one of the path segment strings by readings its address
# from this array of pointers
        .align 2
dirs:   .word up, right, down, left

# Keep the current direction (0-3) in this single byte value
direction:
        .byte 3

        .text
        # $a0 = order (an unsigned integer)
        # $a1 = sign (either 1 or -1)

        .globl dragon

dragon:
        addiu   $sp, $sp, -16           # allocate space on stack (multiple of 8)
        la      $t0, dirs               # t0: dirs array address
        lbu     $t1, direction          # t1: load current direction byte
        move    $t6, $t1                # t6: copy of current direction byte
        li      $t2, 1                  # t2: load constant 1
        li      $t3, -1                 # t3: load constant -1

        sw      $ra, 0($sp)
        sw      $a0, 4($sp)
        sw      $a1, 8($sp)
        beq     $a0, $0, base

        move    $t4, $a1                # t4: keep current sign (1 or -1)
        addiu   $a0, $a0, -1            # order = order - 1
        move    $a1, $t2                # sign = 1
        jal     dragon                  # dragon(order-1, 1)

        li      $v0, print_int
        move    $a0, $a1
        syscall

        addu    $t5, $t6, $t4
        addiu   $t5, $t5, 4
        div     $t5, $t5, 4
        mfhi    $t6                     # t1: (direction + sign + 4) % 4 -> new direction
        sb      $t6, direction

        move    $a1, $t3
        jal     dragon                  # dragon(order-1, -1)
        j       done

base:                                   # when order = 0
        addu    $t1, $t1, $t1
        addu    $t1, $t1, $t1           # direction * 4
        addu    $t5, $t1, $t0           # base address + offset
        lw      $t5, 0($t5)             # t5: direction from array dirs

        li      $v0, print_string
        move    $a0, $t5
        syscall                         # print direction

done:
        lw      $ra, 0($sp)
        lw      $a0, 4($sp)
        lw      $a1, 8($sp)
        addiu   $sp, $sp, 16
        jr      $ra
#
# Main program
#
        .data
svg_header:
        .asciiz "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">\n"
svg_footer:
        .asciiz "</svg>\n"
path_header:
        .asciiz "<path stroke=\"black\" fill=\"none\" d=\"M225 225"
path_footer:
        .asciiz "\" />\n"

        .text

        .globl main
main:
        move    $s0, $ra

        la      $a0, svg_header
        li      $v0, print_string
        syscall

        la      $a0, path_header
        syscall

        li      $a0, 3   # Order
        li      $a1, 1   # Sign
        jal     dragon

        la      $a0, path_footer
        li      $v0, print_string
        syscall

        la      $a0, svg_footer
        syscall

        li      $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: Without a debugger, it's back to good old-fashioned pen and paper: single-step through your program by hand. You may want to focus on `$t1`. It's not saved on the stack, still you continue to use it's value after making a recursive call.

Comment: @RuudHelderman thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding it to the stack but the code is still broken. I've realized that there is a problem with the stack, however, since I keep getting the error "Can't expand stack segment by 16 bytes to 524288 bytes.
Use -lstack # with # > 524288". Am I not clearing the stack properly?

Comment: That's its way of saying Stack Overflow..  Test / debug your code with the smallest possible inputs, so that at first  it shouldn't even recurse.  Then input just 1 larger to see the recursion. Once you get the non-recursive path and the recursive path working, then you can try a larger input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your recursive fragment, you don't return before the `base` bits. So after the second `jal dragon`, your code falls through to the base scenario, which is wrong by any account. By that time, `t1` no longer contains the `direction` variable - it's been multiplied by four. In the `base`, the code tries to resolve `t1` *as if it still was the `direction`* and faults.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still a bit confused though--if I were to return before the `base` bits, would I have to add another `jr $ra` at the end of my dragon label?

Comment: `jr` is not a magical end-of-procedure marker, it's the "return" command in C lingo. That said, you'd want to restore the registers and the SP before you return, so rather than jr before base, place a label at the lw-lw-lw bit in the end of the procedure, and jump there.

Comment: I feel like I have an idea of what you're talking about. I tried fixing my code and edited my original post. If you can, could you check if that is what you were referring to? Sorry to be a bother, my assembly knowledge isn't that great.

Comment: Rather than pasting the fixes separately, just edit the question and paste whole thing, with the fixes applied. Easier for other people to debug. OBTW, I'm not sure about jr at the end of main; that's not usually how you exit in MIPS, try syscall 10 instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I fixed the whole code and changed to syscall 10 in the main. Thankfully, the stack error is fixed, but the output prints out the same direction each time. Would this be a different problem beyond a stack problem?

Comment: At the beginning of each `dragon` run, you load t1 from memory. Then you change the value of t1 but never write it back. Either use a register for the current direction (easier), or save it once you change it.

Comment: would it be sufficient to add `sb      $t1, direction` in between the `mfhi    $t1` and `move    $a1, $t3` instructions?

Comment: Same mistake. **A call to `dragon` messes up the value of t1.** So the whole sequence  - `load t1 - call dragon - change t1` is wrong. By the time the first recursive dragon call returns, the value of t1 is already ruined. So no, it's not enough. You have to give it some thought. I can fix it for you, but that won't be educational, would it?

Comment: ahaha I guess that wouldn't. If I were to use a register for the current direction like you had suggested, would it be like saving the value of direction in a new transition register?

Comment: Yes. But don't take my word for it. **Don't guess, debug.** I don't have QtSpim, but MARS has a nice debugger, with stepping and breakpoints and register viewing.

Comment: thank you so much. I'm not done yet but I definitely feel myself getting closer. As of now, I'm stuck at a point where only the first half is outputting correctly and the second half raises a "Memory Address Out of Bounds" Error. I'm guessing that the first recursive function worked but not the second. What am I missing after making a new register and storing the byte in `direction` after changing?

Comment: You logic for calculating the new direction is off. On the third iteration, direction is 0 and sign is -1. When you add them, you end up with -1 (effectively 0xffffffff). Once you divide, the remainder is -1. Store that in a byte and load again, you have 0xff. Direction should be between 0 and 3.

Comment: Oh, I thought if you used mfhi after the div instruction, it would work the same as the modulus function, which would return 3 for -1 % 4. I didn't realize I could store and load bytes to do that, so I'll try fixing it right now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding by what you mean by storing and loading bytes. Assuming we have the remainder in register $t6, do we store by doing `sb    $t6, 1($t6)` and load with `lb    $t6, 1($16)`?

Comment: I mentioned storing and loading bytes to explain how does -1 in remainder (0xffffffff) become 0xff in $t1 on the next invokation of dragon. I didn't say storing/loading bytes was *wrong*. What is wrong is your assumption that `div` on a negative would produce a positive remainder.

Comment: ahh I get what you meant now. I realized I could just add another 4 to it before I divide to always yield a postive remainder.

Comment: I realized though that $a1 is not changing and thus resulting in stack overflow. I'm not quite sure how this is possible when I'm storing and loading $a1 on the stack?

Comment: My copy, once the division is fixed, doesn't produce a stack overflow. Paste the latest code.

Comment: Pasted. I thought if I prevented the possibility of the remainder becoming negative, it'd be solved, but I guess it's not that easy:(

Comment: The latest code works for me on MARS, prints a well formed SVG: with "M225 225h-5v-5h5v-5h-5v-5h5v-5"

Comment: I do get the same output as yours but I've been given a sample of an order 3 dragon curve, which is the following:
```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path stroke="black" fill="none"
d="M225 225h-5v-5h5v-5h5v5h5v-5" />
</svg>
``` 
it's only a matter of two strokes but I think it may be because the turn was not done correctly

Comment: + the infinite loop happens when I try to print out $a1. this problem really has no end:(

Comment: It only has no end because you are debugging by proxy: you paste the code, I debug. Figure it out already. Download MARS at http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/download.htm, paste the code, and step through it, watching the registers. One note though: MARS starts at the top of the `.text` section, not from `main`. You'd have to place main above dragon.